# GCP Pub/Sub does more retries than configured

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, dead-letter

I have a Pub/Sub push subscription that is triggering Cloud Function. There is retry policy with expotential backoff and dead lettering enabled.

Configuration is next:

- Acknowledge deadline is 60s
- Exactly once delivery enabled
- Maximum delivery attempts is 5
- Miniumn backoff - 30s, maximum backoff - 600s

For testing purposes I configured Cloud Function to always return 500 error code. But instead of 5 retries and 1 event in dead letter topic there was:

- 6 retries and 2 events in dead letter topic
- 7 retries and 3 events in dead letter topic
- 10 retries and 6 events in dead letter topic

I can assume that dead letter topic received more events because there was more retries than expected. But I cannot understand why there was more retries than configured?

Comment: @myhailoroman if you consider the answer above has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pub/Sub has a built in [At-least-once](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery) delivery system which will retry messages that were not acknowledged. In this case, after 600s have passed, the message you first sent becomes unacknowledged, thus Pub/Sub retries the message. It will keep retrying it for 600s until it reaches the messageRetentionDuration or you acknowledge it.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I have configured dead lettering which should limit retries to 5 attempts.
But insted I was receiving messages with deliveryAttempt:5, deliveryAttempt":6, deliveryAttempt":7, etc. 
I am supposing that it's an issue with "exactly once delivery". This feature is in preview mode so might be buggy.
Once I turned it off and set retry policy to "Retry immidiately" it started working as expected.

Comment: As you mention, it might be because the feature is in a preview mode and might be causing issues with your code, so my recommendation for you is that you turn it off so you can make it work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

After much head-scratching and extensive exploration of the pub/sub documentation, I found a solution that worked for me. In my case, we were consuming a deadletter topic from another Google Cloud project, which involves some permission settings for the deadletter configuration of a subscription to work normally.

In my situation, the same behavior was generated. Upon retrying the delivery for the fifth time without success, the subscription would publish the event to the deadletter. In subsequent retries, a new publication to the deadletter topic was made, until the end of the message retention duration of the subscription, or until we cleared the messages from the subscription.

To solve this problem, you will need to grant the roles of publisher and subscriber to the pub/sub service account of the project where the subscription is contained (**pubsub.topics.getIamPolicy** and **pubsub.subscriptions.getIamPolicy**).

**If you access your pub/sub subscription, in the dead leterring tab, you will likely encounter one of the following errors:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO5p5.png

Once correctly configured, the maximum number of retries should be respected.

**For more information, see the following pub/sub documentation:**
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#dead_letter_topic

Specifically, the step: *Pub/Sub only counts delivery attempts when a dead-letter topic is configured correctly and includes the correct IAM permissions.*